# Resizing JPanel causes other components to resize incorrectly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea, gridbaglayout

I'm unable to share my actual code, but the rundown is that I have two JPanels side by side, both with Flow Layouts. You can click a component and have the left JPanel toggle between two sizes. It starts large, and if the button is clicked, all of the contents on the other panel resize perfectly to accommodate for the extra space. However when I click again, the left JPanel gets bigger, but the contents of the right DON'T resize, pushing part of them off the screen.

This bug only happens on some of my tabs, I think it has something to do with the fact that the JPanels with resizing issues contain more JPanels with Flow or Grid Bag Layouts.

I've tried removing thee offending JPanels, resizing, then putting them back in, didn't work. I've tried taking the JPanels out, clearing them, resizing, putting them back in, repopulating them, and that also doesn't work.

If I take the nested JPanels out completely, everything resizes just fine.

I've been able to replicate this issue a bit with this sample code, but can't provide my actual stuff:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.FormFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ResizeExample {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ResizeExample window = new ResizeExample();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ResizeExample() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 734, 605);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
            FormFactory.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
            ColumnSpec.decode("default:grow"),},
        new RowSpec[] {
            RowSpec.decode("default:grow"),}));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "1, 1, fill, fill");
    FormLayout small = new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
            ColumnSpec.decode("50px"),},
        new RowSpec[] {
            RowSpec.decode("default:grow"),});

    FormLayout big = new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
            ColumnSpec.decode("200px"),},
        new RowSpec[] {
            RowSpec.decode("default:grow"),});


    panel.setLayout(big);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("  ");



    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1, "2, 1, fill, fill");
    panel_1.setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
            ColumnSpec.decode("default:grow"),},
        new RowSpec[] {
            RowSpec.decode("default:grow"),}));

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore "
            + "et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo "
            + "consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. "
            + "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    panel_1.add(textArea, "1, 1, fill, center");

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel.removeAll();
            panel_1.removeAll();
            if(panel.getLayout().equals(big))
                panel.setLayout(small);
            else
                panel.setLayout(big);
            panel.add(btnNewButton, "1, 1, center, center");
            panel_1.add(textArea, "1, 1, fill, center");
            frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
            frame.getContentPane().repaint();
        }
    });
    panel.add(btnNewButton, "1, 1, center, center");

    frame.setResizable(false);
}

}
```

Comment: A [mcve] is fine. It is actually better to have a minimal example compared to dropping a lot of code unrelated to the actual problem!